# How to update ng-bind-html every 1 minute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My project is running by Angular Js.
How can i update my element every 1 minute?

This is my element

```
<strong ng-class="{'red-text' : main.redBgArray[$index] == 'red-text'}" ng-bind-html='main.minuteStateCheck(listViewOrder.status,listViewOrder.ordered_at,listViewOrder.accepted_at,listViewOrder.ready_in_mins,$index)'/>
```

So this is my function.

```
vm.minuteStateCheck = function(status,ordered_at,accepted_at,ready_in_mins,index){

    if(status === "pending"){

        vm.ordersStatusRedTextNum = index;

        var differentDayOutput = vm.differenceInDays(ordered_at)

        if(vm.miliSecondCheck > 300000){
            vm.redBgArray[index] = "red-text";
        }

        return differentDayOutput;
    } else 
    if(status === "accepted"){

        var differentDayOutputForAccepted = vm.differentDayOutputForAccepted(accepted_at,ready_in_mins);

        if(vm.miliSecondCheck > 0){
            vm.redBgArray[index] = "red-text";
        }


        return differentDayOutputForAccepted;
    }

}
```

So how can i update my element in every 1 minute?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Ajax time check if status changed? Have you try to use pulling with `setInterval` method?

Comment: i tried setInterval but didn't work

Comment: What was the problem with that?

Comment: If you tried setInterval in angular, and it didn't work, then you should try [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), and also you should read the documentation especially the part regarding the digest cycle (the one that explains `$scope.$apply()`).

Comment: Show the code that didn't work and explain what variables need updating

Comment: i already fixed that by setinterval thanks everyone.